# Justify left and right inside example environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, books, examples

I use the "Numbered Examples (multiline)" environment in a LyX document (class : Book (Standard Class)). The text is not fully justified (it is not right justified) in the examples. Is there a way to modify the environment ? I would prefer to not define a new environment and change all my examples into this new environment and I would prefer not to type ERT[\justify] in all the examples.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You do not need to add your name or thanks to the question, your name is already associated with the question and thanks is expressed by upvoting and accepting answers

Answer (score 3):

I had been looking for a few hours when I posted my question. I have just found out that one solution is to add the following in the preamble.

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
    \let\oldexample\example
    \let\end\oldexample\endexample
    \renewenvironment{example}{\begin{oldexample} \justify}{\end{\oldexample}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.